# Error when checking connection between ec2 insatnce and rds database

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, vpc

I want to test if my ec2 instance can connect to my database.

I ssh into my instance ran the command:

```
echo '\dS' |psql -h rds-endpoint-xxx.amazonaws.com 5432
```

- the result I get is this:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "rds-endpoint-xxx.amazonaws.com" (192.168.12.233) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What does this mean? and what should i do to fix?

- My ec2 instance IP is 192.168.0.138 and in the security group of my rds database I have allowed inbound access from 192.168.0.0
  [image]

Comment: What are security groups?

Comment: @Marcin I updated in question

Comment: @Marcin can u also help with this please

Comment: Is the instance and rds in same VPC?

Comment: @Marcin different VPCs as they are in different aws region but with same VPC CIDRs of 192.168.0.0/16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your two VPC are [peered](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-peering.html), you will not be able to access your RDS from the instance due to your security group (SG). Without peering, the connection from the instance to the rds will **go over internet**, and your SG does not allow internet connections.

To solve this, you either have to peer your VPCs, which you can't do right now as they have same CIDRs. For peering you need **non-overlapping** CIDRs for the VPC.

Alternative is to **allow internet connections** to your RDS, which means you need to allow incoming traffic (0.0.0.0/0) unless you have EIP for the instance. Also RDS must be set to be allow public connections.

Comment: I did finish doing this.. I created new vpc with different cidr which does not overlap, and created the peering connection. now when I run the command again.. I am still getting the same error. Is there any other way to see if my ec2 instance connects with the db ?

Comment: @mgb You can login to the instance, and verify from there.

Comment: how do I verify?